# Form Set Error in custom module

Tags: 7

I am using Drupal7. I also use [ife](https://drupal.org/project/ife) module.  I also wrote a custom module

Here is my code

```
function mymodule_validate($form, &$form_state) {
    $name=$form_state['input']['name'];
    $pass=$form_state['input']['pass'];
    if(empty($pass) || $pass=='') {
           form_set_error('name', t('dummy message'));
        $errors=form_get_errors();
        print_r($errors);
        return $form;
    }
```

I also did some RND. when I check $form_state under complete form I got this array

```
 [complete form] => Array
        (
            [#action] => /logintest/node?destination=node
            [#id] => user-login-form
            [#validate] => Array
                (
                    [0] => user_login_name_validate
                    [1] => user_login_authenticate_validate
                    [2] => user_login_final_validate
                    [3] => mymodule_validate
                    [4] => ife_form_validator
                )
```

Here means the sequence of module working functions.

Now  when I print $errors, 
it is showing

```
Array
(
    [pass] => Password field is required.
    [name] => Sorry, unrecognized username or password. <a href="/logintest/user/password">Have you forgotten your password?</a>
)
```

But I am accepting

```
Array
(
    [pass] => Password field is required.
    [name] => dummy message
)
```

But I don't know why it is not overwriting custom message..  Can anybody tell me how to resolve this issue.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this  under your hook_validate

Here i added new function name mymodule_soft_block_validate

```
 function mymodule_validators() {
        return array('user_login_name_validate', 'user_login_authenticate_validate', 'mymodule_soft_block_validate','user_login_final_validate','mymodule_validate');
    }

function  mymodule_soft_block_validate($form, &$form_state) {
        $pass=$form_state['values']['pass'];
        if(empty($pass) || $pass=='') {
            form_set_error('name', t('dummy message'));
            return $form;
        }           

}
```

Comment: not working/ but message is displaying .

Comment: jst edited the answer again

Comment: yeah its working now

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
$name=$form_state['values']['name'];
$pass=$form_state['values']['pass'];
```

Instead of:

```
$name=$form_state['input']['name'];
$pass=$form_state['input']['pass'];
```

For the rest, I am not sure exactly what is the error. Can you clarify a little bit the use case. Regards !

Comment: i jst want to override form_set_message.

Comment: and above code is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one for setting the error message.

```
function hook_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  if (strlen($form_state['values']['name'])==0) { 
    form_set_error('name', t('word not long enough'));
  }
}
```

Comment: it is showing Username field is required. this message

Comment: not working :).

Comment: you can re order your validate function to be called last in your custom module.

Comment: just done still not working

Answer (score 0):

```
[#validate] => Array
                (
                    [0] => user_login_name_validate
                    [1] => user_login_authenticate_validate
                    [2] => user_login_final_validate
                    [3] => mymodule_validate
                    [4] => ife_form_validator
                )
```

As I can see from your RND that **ife_form_validator** is overriding your messages. For this purpose, you will have to increase the weight of module.

**Drupal 7:**

```
/**
 * Implements hook_enable()
 */
function MODULE_NAME_enable() {
    db_update('system')
    ->fields(array('weight' => 100))
    ->condition('type', 'module')
    ->condition('name', 'MODULE_NAME')
    ->execute();
}
```

**Drupal 6:**

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_install()
 */
function MODULE_NAME_install() {
  drupal_install_schema('devel');

  // New module weights in core: put devel as the very last in the chain.
  db_query("UPDATE {system} SET weight = 100 WHERE name = 'MODULE_NAME'");

  ...
}
```

I would suggest that you verify the weight of **ife_form_validator** module first. Then, increase the weight of the module in which you are using the following code:

```
function mymodule_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  $name=$form_state['input']['name'];
  $pass=$form_state['input']['pass'];
  if(empty($pass) || $pass=='') {
    form_set_error('name', t('dummy message'));
    $errors=form_get_errors();
    print_r($errors);
    return $form;
}
```

Comment: jst tried. given weight 2000 to mymodule as ife having weigth of 1000.. still not working .

Comment: [#validate] => Array
                (
                    [0] => user_login_name_validate
                    [1] => user_login_authenticate_validate
                    [2] => user_login_final_validate
                    [3] => ife_form_validator
                    [4] => loginsecurity_validate
                )